# Como crear varios botones en un mismo formulario HTML / PHP?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli, formularios

Estoy iniciando el aprendizaje de formularios en HTML y PHP, ya logre crear un boton que envia los datos ingresados a una base de datos MySQL ingresados por el usuario.

Mi pregunta es,como puedo poner mas botones en el mismo formulario y que cada uno realize una accion diferente?. Pregunto esto por que por lo que he entendido la parte de "action" dentro del codigo del formulario es la accion que se lleva acabo cuando das click en el boton.

Ejemplo:

```
<div><center>
<form method="post" action="InsertarSQL.php" class="forma">
```

Codigo completo del formulario

```
  <div><center>
  <form method="post" action="InsertarSQL.php" class="forma">
  <input type="Text" name="apellido_pat" placeholder="Apellido Paterno"><br> 
  <br>
  <input type="Text" name="apellido_mat" placeholder="Apellido Materno"><br> 
  <br>
  <input type="Text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"><br><br>
  <input type="Text" name="puesto" placeholder="Puesto"><br><br>
  <input type="Text" name="edad" placeholder = "Edad"><br><br>
  <input type="Submit" name="enviar" value="Agregar registro">
  </form>
  </center></div>
  </div></center>

  <a href="Principal.html" class="init">Inicio</a>
  </body>
```

Comment: Qué acciones quieres que haga cada botón exactamente?

Comment: Pues por ejemplo, el boton que tengo envia los registros a la base, pero si quisiera poner un boton que en ese mismo formulario, hiciera la consulta de la datos actuales en la base. Como decirle al nuevo boton que usara por ejemplo el archivo Consulta.php si la parte de action ya esta ocupada por "InsertarSQL.php"?

Comment: Puedes tener varios botones con diferentes `value` pero la pagina del `action` será la misma, en esa página es donde tienes que ver que `value` ha llegado y realizar la acción correspondiente

Comment: Otra opción sería que tú action del form lleve a un controlador. Cada botón submit lo llamas de una manera y le pones un valor. Luego tu controlador analiza primero que botón es el que has pulsado y realizas la acción que te interesa. Así empiezas a diseñar un CRUD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<form id='form1' name='form1'>
    <input type="button" value="Crear usuario" id="nuevo" name="nuevo" onclick= "document.form1.action = 'nuevo.php'; 
    document.form1.submit()" />

    <input type="button" value="Eliminar usuario" id="eliminar"
    name="eliminar" onclick= "document.form1.action = 'eliminar.php'; document.form1.submit()" />
</form>
```

**o puedes**
Capturar el boton pulsado en el controlador

```html
<form action="/TransaccionSQL.php" name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Crear usuario" id="evento_nuevo"    name="evento_nuevo" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Eliminar usuario" id="evento_eliminar" name="evento_eliminar" />
</form>
```

```
$add=$_POST["evento_nuevo"];
$del=$_POST["evento_eliminar"];
if($add!=null){
  /*####*/
}
if($del!=null){
  /*####*/
}
```

**Referencia**
https://olgacarreras.blogspot.com/2007/02/formulario-con-varios-botones.html

Comment: Pero y si lo que quiero es enviar el form del `index.php` a un archivo, que ponga, por ejemplo `Hola, Usuario` y que este mismo archivo tenga un botón que haga `href` a otra página que ponga también `Bienvenido, Usuario` ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes poner un boton de type="submit" y los otros botonos con el type="button"

Otra alternativa es agregar en el formulario el evento  onsubmit="return 0;"
y agregar eventos independientes para cada boton ya sea con el onclick u otro que se ajuste a tu necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un name="valorDiferente" en cada submit y que tu formulario lleve a una condicion.

```
<form action="fin.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="texto">
  <input type="submit" value="Agregar" name="add">
  <input type="submit" value="Quitar" name="less">
</form>
```

En php hacer las validaciones adecuadas:

```
<?php 
  $texto = $_POST['texto'];
  if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    echo "el texto: ".$texto.". Sera agregado.<br>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['less'])){
    echo "el texto: ".$texto.". Sera elimniado.<br>";
  }
?>
```